Task.WhenAll() Task was canceled when used with ContinueWith() on awaited tasks
When creating list of tasks that needs to be executed some of them can fail but that should not stop execution of code, I came up with usage of continuewith for only on faulted tasks, but when Task.WhenAll() is called on task collection it throws exception that task was canceled:
The code snippet that is used:
 var deletOldFiles = dbDraft
                    ?.Documents?.Select(s => s.Id)
                    .Select(id =>
                        _fileStorage
                            .DeleteFileAsync(
                                _fileStorageConfiguration.DefaultFileCollectionName,
                                id,
                                cancellationToken
                            )
                            .ContinueWith(
                                t =>
                                {
                                    _logger.LogError(
                                        "Could not delete document with identifier: {id}",
                                        id
                                    );
                                },
                                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted
                            )
                    );

                if (deletOldFiles is not null)
                    await Task.WhenAll(deletOldFiles);

Even though when Task.WhenAll is called, main task DeleteFileAsync() executes successfully but Task.WhenAll throws an exception.
When I remove ContinueWith() call, code works fine and Task.WhenAll() is completed. But I want if some of file deletion fails, to continue with deletion of other files.

Are you getting TaskCancelledException during Task.WhenAll method call?

You don't need such convoluted code. TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted doesn't hide cancellations anyway

There's no need for such convoluted code. You can't hide exceptions with ContinueWith either, you have to use proper exception handling.
For starters, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted only runs on actual faults, not cancellations. If the cancellation token gets signaled all remaining operations will be cancelled and await Task.WhenAll will throw as expected.
On top of that, ContinueWith does NOT hide the exception. As the OnlyOnFaulted docs explain :

If you do not access the Exception property, the exception is unhandled.

Finally, it's not a good idea to fire off all operations at once. Whether the code deletes local files or calls a service, there's always a limit to how many operations can run concurrently, after which performance drops dramatically.
Parallel.ForEachAsync
At the very least the code can be replaced with this, using Parallel.ForEachAsync
var stuff= dbDraft?.Documents?.Select(s => s.Id);
var collection=_fileStorageConfiguration.DefaultFileCollectionName;
if (stuff is {} ids)
{   
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(ids,cancellationToken,(id,ct)=>{
        try 
        {
            _fileStorage.DeleteFileAsync(collection,id,ct);
            _logger.LogInfo("Deleted: {id}",id);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex,"Could not delete document with identifier: {id}",id);
        }
    });
}

If the outer cancellation token is signaled, the parallel loop will get canceled and await Parallel.ForEachAsync will throw the expected exception. The application should catch and handle this exception :
try
{
    var stuff=...
}
catch(TaskCancelledException ex)
{
    // Log? Do nothing?
}

By default ForEachAsync uses as many concurrent worker tasks as there are cores. This can change by passing a ParallelOptions argument :
var opt=new ParallelOptions { 
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 12,
            CancellationToken = cancellationToken
        };
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(ids,opt,(id,ct)=>{
...

TPL Dataflow blocks
Another option is to use an ActionBlock class and post messages to it for processing. ActionBlock and the other Dataflow classes like TransformBlock have input and output buffers (when applicable). By default they only process one message at a time. Parallelism is achieved by connecting multiple blocks together with LinkTo to construct a pipeline, just like a shell script.
In the question's case, the code could look like this. In this example the Capacity ensures we don't flood the buffer with requests if the operation is too slow:
var opt=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
      {
         BoundedCapacity = 16,
         MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4,
         CancellationToken = cancellationToken
      }

var block=new ActionBlock<int>(id=>ThatMethod(id,cancellationToken),opt);

foreach(var id in ids)
{
    await block.SendAsync(id);
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;

Any exceptions surface in await block.Completion. To handle cancellation :
try
{
    await block.Completion;
}
catch(TaskCancellationException ex)
{
...
}

This may look like too much extra work compared to ForEachAsync. The real power comes from linking multiple blocks together though. In that case, if one block pauses, the pause is propagated back up the pipeline. When an upstream block completes, completion is propagated to the next block :
var dbLoader=new TransformManyBlock<string,int>(category=>{
    try
    {
        var query=dbDraft.Documents
                         .Where(d=>d.Category==category)
                         .Select(d=>d.id);
        return query;
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         _logger.LogError(ex,"Db Error for {category}",category);
         return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
     }
},loaderOptions);

var deleter=var block=new ActionBlock<int>(id=>ThatMethod(id,cancellationToken),deleterOptions);

var linkOptions=new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = True};

dbLoader.LinkTo(deleter);

With the pipeline ready, we can start sending messages to the loader and wait until the deleter completes. TransformManyBlock converts any IEnumerable<T> to individual T messages before passing them to the next block.
foreach(var id in ids)
{
    await dbLoader.SendAsync(id);
}

dbLoader.Complete();
await deleter.Completion;


Answering the exact question
To hide cancellations with a single continuation, the flag should be NotOnRanToCompletion. OnlyOnFaulted is defined as OnlyOnFaulted = NotOnRanToCompletion | NotOnCanceled,
.ContinueWith(t =>
    {    
        _logger.LogError("Could not delete document with identifier: {id}",id);
    },
    TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion
)

This isn't a good practice in 2024 though, as there are far better constructs. This is how things were done in 2010 when there was no async/await and even Dataflow was experimental

Thank you for your detailed explanation. The issue was about awaiting tasks that are returned by ContinueWith() with TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted that are on time when DeleteFileAsync() is completed are canceled, so Task.WhenAll() throws an exception that task was canceled (the on returned by ContinueWith()). Approach that I took is to remove TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted and check the status of Task t parameter, T.IsFaulted and log exception. I understand you point about parallelism and makes sense, so definitely will apply you advices. Thanks a lot!

@dbuvac cancellation isn't a fault, which is why the code and the assumptions behind it don't work. If you wanted to hide cancellations you should have added another ContinueWith with OnlyOnCancelled. None of this is a good practice in 2024 though. Yes, that's how we worked in 2010, but since 2012 there's no reason

@dbuvac I added an example that shows how you can actually capture both cancellation and faults by using the NotOnRanToCompletion flag. This is really not a good idea though

ContinueWith() task is cancelled when condition of its execution is not satisifed, ie in your case when precedent task was completed without errors.
And because of you return ContinueWith() tasks, Task.WhenAll method operates with all continuations, not original tasks.
Quick fix - return original tasks, ignoring cancellations:
var deletOldFiles = dbDraft
    ?.Documents?.Select(s => s.Id)
    .Select(id =>
        {
            var t = _fileStorage
                .DeleteFileAsync(
                    _fileStorageConfiguration.DefaultFileCollectionName,
                    id,
                    cancellationToken
                );
            t.ContinueWith(
                pt =>
                {
                    _logger.LogError(
                        "Could not delete document with identifier: {id}",
                        id
                    );
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
            return t;
        }
    );

if (deletOldFiles is not null)
    await Task.WhenAll(deletOldFiles);

There are a couple of moments to mention:

Do you need Enumerable.Select call twice? Once would be enough.
Why do you need null propagation for dbDraft? Can it be null,
seriously?

UPDATE
Especially for my friend @Panagiotis, who always requires blameless and clear code samples.
Check out output of this code:
var ids = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
var continues = new Task[10];
var tasks = ids.Select(id =>
{
    var t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // if (id % 2 == 0)
        //         throw new InvalidOperationException($"id:{id} is even");
        Console.WriteLine($"TaskId: {id}");
    });
    
    var cnTask = t.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Task with Id:{id} faulted...");
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    continues[id] = cnTask;
    return t;
});

var aggregate = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var exc = aggregate.Exception;
try
{
    await aggregate;
    Console.WriteLine("Completed execution");
    Console.WriteLine("Continuation tasks: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < continues.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i}: {continues[i].Status}");
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}


This isn't ignoring cancellations. It's no different from the original code. If the token is signaled all the tasks returned by DeleteFileAsync will be cancelled. Cancellation isn't a fault so the continuation isn't called upon cancellation.

@PanagiotisKanavos i am talking about implicit cancellation of ContinueWith() tasks, not about possible effect of CancellationToken explicitly passed.

There's no cancellation in the continuation, either in the question or this answer. Unless DeleteFileAsync throws, this is almost identical to the question. The difference is that this code would fail to log if a cancellation and exception overlapped

I've made an mre before posting answer - yes, it does exist. Implicit one.

What does exist? What did you test? This isn't up to debate, it's how things work for the last 14 years - TPL was introduced in 2010, and before async/await people used ContinueWith for everything. In this question's codethere's noCancellationTokenpassed toContinueWith. This question's ContinueWithwon't cancel. BUT unless an exception is thrown, it won't run either. The result will be the task returned byDeleteFileAsync`

Okay, let me show you.

If you check the actual definition of OnlyOnFaulted you'll see it's OnlyOnFaulted = NotOnRanToCompletion | NotOnCanceled. If your t is in the Cancelled state, the continuation won't run. But you're still returning a cancelled t, so Task.WhenAll will also get cancelled.

As the Task.WhenAll docs say: If none of the supplied tasks faulted but at least one of them was canceled, the returned task will end in the Canceled state.

@PanagiotisKanavos, updated answer. Sometimes ability to get thoughts might be used as a marker for good teamplayer, who often grasps all the ideas without saying. Especially valuable for folks whose english is not native enough.

This isn't about ideas or clear samples. You claim something that's simply wrong. What you posted doesn't even use a CancellationToken so it doesn't prove that returning the original cancelled task won't result in another exception. Try await TaskDelay(50000, cancellationToken) with a token created from a new CancellationTokenSource(10) instead of Task.Run

Referring to OPs: but when Task.WhenAll() is called on task collection it throws exception that task was canceled:  - When is it possible? Exclude the case of explicit cancellation. This is so straightforward, i don't get why all this talk is made.

Explicit cancellation should be handled separately, of course. How often tasks are cancelled? Meaning - what is OPs real problem?
